# Rails Refactoring Block in Views - can I write this more efficiently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, view

I'm trying to setup logic for my tables in rails. Basically its a timesheet application and what I want to do is set it up show it shows green if you hit your goal. Yellow if you are almost there. And red if you aren't even close. The code I have below works. However looking at my logs, it seems horribly inefficient. How can I write this better?

Here is the view. users/hours.html.erb

```
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Weekly Timesheets</h1></div>

<table class="nicetable table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Total Hours</th>
      <th>Role</th>
      <th>Change Role</th>
      <th>Timesheet</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr class="<%= 'success' if user.has_role? :staff and user.add_hours >= 10 %><%= 'warning' if user.has_role? :staff and user.add_hours < 10 and user.add_hours > 6 %><%= 'error' if user.has_role? :staff and user.add_hours >= 0 and user.add_hours <= 6 %><%= 'success' if user.has_role? :new_staff and user.add_hours >= 15 %><%= 'warning' if user.has_role? :new_staff and user.add_hours < 15 and user.add_hours >= 12 %><%= 'error' if user.has_role? :new_staff and user.add_hours < 12 and user.add_hours >= 0 %>">
      <td><%= user.name%></td>
      <td><%= user.email %></td>
      <td><%= user.add_hours %></td>
      <td><%= user.roles.first.name.titleize unless user.roles.first.nil? %></td>
      <td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Change role</a>
        <%= render user %>
      </td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Timesheet', user_timesheets_path(user, @timesheets), class: "btn btn-mini" %>
    </tr>
```

And here is my Users Model.

```
    def add_hours
  self.timesheets.where('day BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today.beginning_of_week, Date.today.end_of_week).order('created_at DESC').sum{|p| p.teacher + p.conversation + p.study}

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a refactored version. I've made the following changes:

- pulled out the status logic into user#progress_status and refactored it to make it more reusable and to cleanup the view
- used for loop in the view since it is more readable
- renamed user#add_hours to total_hours so it doesn't imply addition (command) but just a virtual attribute (which is a query)
- removed the order scope in the method since you don't need one this case
- made the total_hours cache its result on the user, so multiple subsequent calls don't hit the DB multiple times (as we do inside progress status)

First the view. I've included only the content inside tbody:

```
<% for user in @users %>                                                         
    <tr class="<%= user.progress_status.to_s %>">                                  
      <td><%= user.name %></td>                                                    
      <td><%= user.email %></td>                                                   
      <td><%= user.total_hours %></td>                                               
      <td><%= user.roles.first and user.roles.first.name.titleize %></td>          
      <td>                                                                         
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#role-options-<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-mini" type="button">Change role</a>
        <%= render user %>                                                         
      </td>                                                                        
      <td><%= link_to 'Timesheet', user_timesheets_path(user, @timesheets), class: "btn btn-mini" %></td>
    </tr>                                                                          
  <% end %>
```

And the refactored user model methods:

```
def total_hours                                                                    
  @total_hours ||= timesheets                                                   
    .where('day BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today.beginning_of_week, Date.today.end_of_week)
    .sum {|p| p.teacher + p.conversation + p.study}                             
end                                                                             

def progress_status                                                             
  if has_role? :staff                                                           
    if total_hours >= 10                                                           
      :success                                                                     
    elsif (7..9).include? total_hours                                           
      :warning                                                                     
    else                                                                           
      :error                                                                       
    end                                                                                                                                         
  elsif has_role? :new_staff                                                       
    if total_hours >= 15                                                           
      :success                                                                     
    elsif (12..14).include? total_hours                                            
      :warning                                                                     
    else                                                                           
      :error
    end
  end
end
```

You could go a bit further with the last method (when more context provided), but it should be OK for now.

Comment: Ok so this is the one I ended up going with. All of the answers below were great as well though. There was one thing I did have to change though. For the view, I had to change `<td><%= user.add_hours %></td>  ` to `<td><%= user.total_hours %></td> ` and it worked. This solution worked beautifully and reduced the load. Thank you so much! As a beginner rails programmer, I thank you!

Comment: You're right, it was a typo which I corrected now for the future references. Glad it helped =)

Answer (score 1):

What dax said is correct, but please, don't put that code in you model.
You could use the presenter pattern or the decorator pattern. I find the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)
very usefull. 
In your case you would create a user decorator with all the methods that return data specifically for this view. Something like:

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def role_name
    object.roles.first.name.titleize if object.roles.first.present?
  end

  def hours_stauts
    if object.add_hours >= hours_success
      'success'
    elsif object.add_hours >= hours_warning
      'warning'
    else
      'error'
    end
  end

  def hours_success
    object.has_role? :staff ? 10 : 15
  end

  def hours_warning
    object.has_role? :staff ? 6 : 12
  end
end
```

You can add any methods needed for this or other views. Read the draper documentation onhow to use the gem.

Comment: I don't think this case is a good one for those patterns. Most of this code smells of domain logic (apart from #role_name), so it should ideally be put into a domain model. Which makes it more reusable than a decorator/presenter pattern. At first we can put it into AR model (it does the job at the beginning) and we can extract it later into a domain class (and avoid fat model anti-pattern).

Comment: I'll have to look into this later. For now the other solution worked. Thanks for letting me know about draper!

Comment: Well, the amount of hours could be in the domain model, I really don't know what those hours mean, but the css class must not go in the model... that's pure presentation logic as well as the role name titelization.
If you move the hours configurations to the role model your presenter would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work!

In `user.rb`:

```
def user_css
  if self.has_role? :staff do |staff|
    if staff.add_hours >= 10
      'success'
    elsif staff.add_hours >= 6
      'warning'
    else
      'error'
  end
  if self.has_role? :new_staff do |new_staff|
    if new_staff.add_hours >= 15
      'success'
    elsif new_staff.add_hours >= 12
      'warning'
    else
      'error'
  end
end
```

in your `view`

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr class="<%= user.user_css %>">
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This one would have worked also, however I liked the logic jurglic used for calculating the hours. Thanks for replying so quickly!